# Trusty Tahr upgrade problem

Tags: dual-boot, upgrade, system-installation

I want to upgrade from saucy to Trusty Tahr.I made a bootable DVD of Trusty.But when I boot from the DVD the installation gives me these options

A dual boot win7 and ubuntu 13.10 detected.
1.Remove ubuntu 13.10 do a fress install
2.Remove Win 7
3.Remmove both
4.Other

I just want to upgrade to Trusty without loosing my Apps and settings.

I tried upgrading from software updater but it is not showing NEW releases.I tried changing the server locations but no use.Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you upgrade from 13.10 to 14.04, the update manager should show you the new release within the next days automatically.

You can force the update manager to show the new release by using the command

```
update-manager -d
```

Keep in mind to create a backup of all your files before upgrading.